# Deleting Dead User Accounts from Sharepoint Alerts,Assigned to E-Mails ,Workflows

Tags: powershell, feature, jquery, content

how delete Dead User Accounts from Sharepoint Alerts,Assigned to E-Mails ,Workflows.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the root site of the site collection, Then go to the _catalogs/users/simple.aspx page of the root of the site collection.  Click on the user you want to delete, and select delete user from site collection.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:  [Find and Delete Orphaned Alerts in SharePoint](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/12/find-and-delete-orphaned-alerts-in-sharepoint.html)